# C# MVC2 how to add data two related table in different column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I want insert data into two, related tables. My first table is `asset`; this table has 14 columns, eg. `assetid`, `assetype`, `assetsize`, and so on. The second table is the `Owner` table, the columns are `OwnerId`, `assetid`, `ownername`, `contactno`, `address` and `emailid`.

My `asseetid` column (from the `asset` table) is the primary key of the first table. `Ownerid` is also a primary key, on the second table; these are auto generated.

I want the second table to get the `assetid` in first table and another column I filled. All my columns are declared `not null`. Please help me how to store data in my tables.

Comment: Please reformat your question its impossible to read. and please check the grammar to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us the cardinality of asset to owner; is it one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many?

I think it sounds like many-to-many -- each asset can have many owners, and each owner can have many assets. If that's the case, you need to create a join table; depending on your ORM (Entity, NHibernate, etc.) there are different ways of doing it.

I've only used NHibernate with ActiveRecord, so I can only comment on that. You need to create a join table (asset_owner) with two foreign key references (assetid and ownerid), and you need to annotate your classes with HasMany and BelongsTo, like so: http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/gettingstarted/relations.html